# strcpy seg fault in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcpy

Curious about what is going wrong with this strcpy.

```
int main(void){
    char *history[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        history[i] = NULL;
    }
    char line[80];
    fgets(line,80,stdin); 
    strcpy(history[0],line); //This line segfaults
}
```

Comment: You are doing `strcpy(NULL, line)`.

Comment: You forgot to assign storage to `history[0]`, so of course it blows up.  You can use `history[0] = strdup(line)` instead.

Comment: modify the definition of history by `char history[10]`, and use `strcpy(history, line)`, since `char *` declares that the element of history is a pointer, not a character.

Answer (score 4):

You've created an array of NULL pointers. You then tried to copy characters onto NULL.  That's a no-no.

EDIT:
Your program could be optimized to this:

```
void main() {
   char line[80];
   fgets(line,80,stdin); 
}
```

Your history array is never used to generate any output. So, while others have pointed out you need to allocate memory, technically, you could simply do this:

```
history[0] = line;
```

That will be a valid pointer up until the line goes out of scope, which is when history goes out of scope so it won't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory for `history[0]`. As `history[0]` is assigned NULL referencing it or writing to it will/may cause segfault.

something like

```
//this will create memory for 100 chars
history[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100); 
strcpy(history[0],line);
```

Or

```
//shortcut for both - this allocate new memory and returns pointer.
history[0] = strdup(line);
```

Comment: What is the best thing to initialize the history to? Also thank you for the help

Comment: @MoStack, initialize to NULL is fine, but when you want to use it to store chars you should allocate memory to it.

Comment: This answer would be fantastic, if only you replaced "will/may cause segfault" to "may behave erratically". The reason you can't say it "will cause a segfault" is that gives a definition; that defines the outcome, where-as in standard C the outcome is considered *undefined*. Other things could happen, too. Notable examples of *undefined behaviour* which often don't cause segfaults include: vulnerabilities such as buffer overflows and format string vulns, race conditions (multiple threads accessing the same resource at the same time), signed integer overflow and... this, if run on some devices.